# How to check if only one position in a list is blank and all others are not

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
list = [' ' for x in range(10)]
```

If I add values to this list, how do I check that only list[0] is blank and list[1] - list[9] are not?

Comment: Is a blank string a) an empty string; b) a single-character string that contains a space; c) a more-than-length-one string that contains spaces; d) a string that only contains whitespace (such as newlines and tabs); e) all of the above?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Also, you are shadowing the built-in ```list``` function by assigning it as a variable

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `l` is the list containing the values, you can do something like:

```py
if l[0] == ' ' and all(s != ' ' for s in l[1:9]):
    print("Complete!!!!!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `all`

```
list1=[' ' if i==0 else i for i in range(10) ]
if list1[0]==" " and all(x!=' ' for x in list1[1:9]):
    print("Complete List!!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, most straight forward way is to just write a loop to go through each element. Keep track of what the element is and then do something with that information.

A way for you to know that would constant time would be to track how many different indices you have changed, and then to just check how many empty spaces there are left.